# Spark, Scala, Streaming Twitter

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, streaming

I wrote a scala script in Ubuntu  home path as abc.scala and hardcoded all oauth values from twitter app:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)

val filters="Raj"
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterPopularTags").setMaster("local[2]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters)
```

I execute is as

```
$Spark_bin-2.7> cat abc.scala | ./spark-shell
```

It runs till StreamingContext. But when it reaches TwitterUtils, It gives and error reading thus:

> Error: not found: TwitterUtils

I downloaded latest Spark 2.0.1. Can you point out the settings or documents step by step?

Comment: Did you add the dependency for twitter streaming?

Comment: Do you have the steps that I can add the dependency?                                                               Running Spark application reading Twitter(spark 2.0.1), Scala 2.11.8, Java 8 on Linux( Ubuntu 16.1) gives me an error:

it gives and error---
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

I tried all 4 paramters, filters, DISK_ONLY_2 too but it's not working and complains at TwitterUtils.createStream()

raja@ubuntu:/usr/local/spark/bin$ cat twitter_script|spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Add org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:1.6.1 to spark-shell like

```
$Spark_bin-2.7> cat abc.scala | ./spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:1.6.1
```

Use this approach

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)

sc.stop()
val filters="Raj"
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterPopularTags").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters)
```